# "Guard" operator like JavaScript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I like to do this in JavaScript:

```
function (a, b, c) {
    var foo = a || b || c;
    return foo.bar;
}
```

Is there a quick way to do assignment with fallback or does it require a custom `function`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PHP 5.3 introduces the `?:` operator (not to be confused with the ternary conditional, go figure). I don't use PHP, but I imagine it'd be something like:

```
 $foo = $a ?: $b ?: $c
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> > Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression **expr1 ?: expr3** returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Happy coding.

Comment: Not sure what to make of your first sentence. Also note that this is only of limited use due to the comparison being made with equality, e.g. `a=false,b=0,c=1` will return 1. Also note that it will return the *result of the expression*, so `isset(data[a]) ?: 'bar'` will return `true` when data[a] is set; when you might expect it to return the value of data[a] instead. On a sidenote, the manual suggests not to stack ternarys.

Comment: @Gordon True... it's mashed up as "special ternary conditional syntax" in PHP. I guess I'm just used to it being called "or" or similar. As far as returning the result of the expression -- that's the long-absent feature that it adds ;-) I guess, `a ?: b` can be though of as a "shortcut syntax" for  `a ? a : b` that avoids evaluation of `a` twice. I have no idea how the other quirks of `?:` affect it. Nesting isn't an issue because there is no ambiguity wrt. intent and syntax -- outside of precedence -- as it is a binary operator (vs. a ternary operator like the other form).